# PHP Class code not working

Tags: php, oop

I coded a very simple PHP class. but its not working. my PHP version is: 5.4.16
here is my my PHP code:

```
class FirstClass
{
    public $name = "hello, world!"; 

    public function displayName()
    {
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
```

I know its a very simple PHP code, but dont know why its not working. its also not giving any error or warning. I'm still new to PHP and trying to understand how PHP is working.

Comment: You must call the function to execute it.

Comment: Adding the line, `displayname();` will do the work.

Comment: this should work have you create the object of class and call the public method `displayName()`

Comment: can you guys tell how to do that? example code will be helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just created the class and definition for the function, however you are not executing it. Try this,

```
<?php
    class FirstClass
    {
        public $name = "hello, world!"; 

        public function displayName()
        {
            echo $this->name;
        }

    }

    $firstclass=new FirstClass; // Object for the class

    $firstclass->displayName(); // Call the function with the object
?>
```

[Demo here.](http://codepad.org/1KMXyXTX)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
class FirstClass
{
    public $name = "hello, world!"; 

    public function displayName()
    {
    return $this->name;
    }
}

$obj = new FirstClass();//Creating an object of the class
echo $obj->displayName();//Calling the function
```

You just created the class and defined the functions in the class. But you never invoked the class and its functions.For executing the statements inside a function in a class you need to do two things.

1. Create an object of the class
2. Using that object call the function which contains desired code.

And [see this](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php) for more in the documentation

Comment: The `displayName` method already have `echo`. There is no need to write `echo` again when you are executing it.

Answer (score 1):

This must be working if you create an object of your class and call your function

like this

```
class FirstClass
{
    public $name = "hello, world!"; 

    public function displayName()
    {
    echo $this->name;
    }
}

$obj = new FirstClass();
$obj->displayName();
```

SEE **[DEMO](https://eval.in/186344)**

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Are you by any chance not instantiating the class?

```
    $foo = new FirstClass();
    $foo->displayName();
```

A class is kinda like a description. It doesn't really do anything by itself unless it has static properties/methods. You have to create a new FirstClass object.